# Cannot check that object is an HTMLDocument using instanceof

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I found out that `if (target instanceof HTMLDocument)` is always false. The explanations appears to be that [`HTMLDocument` is just an historical relic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument), but then I'd at least have expected to be able to use `target instanceof Document` instead; that also doesn't work, I guess because `Document`'s prototype is called `HTMLDocumentPrototype` in Firefox and `Document` in Chrome – and yet, `target instanceof Document` still evaluates to `false` in Chrome.

In the end I resorted to using `target.toString() === "[object HTMLDocument]"`, that seems to work both in Firefox and Chrome and is mentioned as a strategy in the very good [modern Javascript tutorial](https://javascript.info/instanceof#bonus-object-prototype-tostring-for-the-type); still, I would like to understand if it is the right way to check if my target is a Document or a different kind of `Node`, and why `target instanceof Document` does not work in Chrome even if `Document` is in the prototype chain, and why `HTMLDocumentPrototype`, that is in the prototype chain of `Document` in Firefox, is shown as `undefined` in the developer's tools... I am confused.

Comment: "*I found out that `if (target instanceof HTMLDocument)` is always false*" - well what is `target`? For me, `document instanceof Document` is true.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to understand if it is the right way to check if my target is a Document or a different kind of `Node`

The proper way to check that is to look at the [`.nodetype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType):

```
if (target.nodetype == Node.DOCUMENT_NODE)
```